# How to? Smoke Simulation Pressurized Steam

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

Can anyone suggest the best method of creating Pressure Steam in Blender? I have tried Mantaflow with little luck.
here is a source image I am trying to emulate.
thank you all.
[image: steam example]

Comment: try using particles

Comment: That's my next best bet at this point.

Comment: try giving a shot to emberGen, then you can export the volumes to blender